# how to add and get class's object values in HashMap

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashmap, classcastexception

I want to create a method to add data into `sqlite` database which take `HashMap<String,Person>` as argument in a class.

From another class, I want to add person details in `HashMap<String,Person>` that can be used by my database handler class.

I have search a lot and tried many examples for this, but couldn't get the solution. Now i'm bit confused how to do this.

I am doing this in following manner now, and getting `ClassCastException`.

**Class 1 :PersonDataSource.java**

```
public long createContact(HashMap<String, Contact> queryValues) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();    
Contact val = Contact.class.cast(queryValues);   

values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,  val.getFirstName());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, val.getLastName());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NICK_NAME, val.getNickName());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BIRTHDATE, val.getBirthDate());  
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRIMARY_CONTACT, val.getPrimaryContact());

long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
return insertId;
}
```

And form another class :

```
datasource = new ContactDataSource(this);
datasource.open();

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,null,null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));

          Person data = new Person();
          data.setNickName(name);
          data.setPrimaryContact(phoneNumber);

          HashMap<String, Person> map =  new  HashMap<String, Person>();
          map.put("data", data);

          long id = datasource.createContact(map);

          Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Contact id :" + String.valueOf(id));
        }
        phones.close();
        datasource.close();
```

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Contact val = (Contact) queryValues.get("data");
```

Instead of

```
Contact val = Contact.class.cast(queryValues);
```

---

This is because, you are trying to put a single contact into map as `map.put("data", data);` so when you will read this entry, you need to use `map.get("data")` because here key is `data`.

Comment: Great, did the job. Can you provide some explanation about the problem ??

Comment: @I-droid Added explanation. If there any confusion feel free to ask.. :)